# How to get data change notifications from SQL Express 2012?

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express, delphi-xe4, service-broker

We have client - server application, where client is built in Delphi XE4 and server uses SQL Server 2012 Express edition. Can my delphi application (using WMI for server events) receive data change notifications from Express edition?

The documentation says that Express edition supports service broker as "Client Only".

Is it possible to achieve the above functionality using Express edition with out the help of any other sql server edition in between.

Comment: please calrify on what you mean by data change notifications

Comment: @TheGameiswar It's pretty clear what OP is looking for, and the term speaks for itself.

Comment: If any data in the table_x changes for the query (select * from table_x), then I would like to receive a notification from SQL Service.

Comment: please update the question with some sample as well

Comment: MS know what they are doing when it comes to restricting features available in various s/ware editions.  So if they say "Client only" I imagine they mean it.  What they mean by it is another kettle of fish.  Your best bet might be to ask in EMB's FireDAC newsgroup:https://forums.embarcadero.com/forum.jspa?forumID=502, as FireDAC uses server broker notifications, iirc.  FD's author is very active there and I'd be surprised if he doesn't know whether notifications are supported in the Express edition.

Comment: @TheGameiswar: about change notifications, see e.g. here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Database_Alerts_%28FireDAC%29.  FDac arrived later than XE4 iirc, but its Sql Server alerts notifications are based on service broker ones.

Comment: @MartynA Query Notifications use Service Broker in local only mode and this mode is fully functional in Express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. [Query Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SQLDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx) are fully functional in Express editions. [Working with Query Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx) explains how to use Query Notifications directly from OleDB (via `SSPROP_QP_NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT`, `SSPROP_QP_NOTIFICATION_MSGTEXT` and `SSPROP_QP_NOTIFICATION_OPTIONS`) and from ODBC (via `SQL_SOPT_SS_QUERYNOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT`, `SQL_SOPT_SS_QUERYNOTIFICATION_MSGTEXT` and `SQL_SOPT_SS_QUERYNOTIFICATION_OPTIONS`). I don't know if Delphi exposes Query Notifications at higher level or you would have to code against low level ODBC or OLEDB. The really usable options are exposed via managed driver in C# et all, via `SQLDependency` class.

I see in the [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Database_Alerts_%28FireDAC%29) MartynA posted the XE8 supports Query Notifications. It should work with Express.

The 'client only' restriction for Express refers strictly to Service Broker remote communications (exchanging messages between SQL Server instances), a capability not needed for Query Notifications.

Comment: Thank you. We are looking for XE8 to be able to use query notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this feature with only Express edition.

You need at least Standard Edition to get the SQL Server Service Broker backend up and running. Once you have one Standard editon instance other Express edition instances can participate.

Comment: This is plain wrong.  Service Broker in local mode, as used by Query Notifications, is fully functional in Express.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I stand corrected :-). It was under the impression that Query Notifications was linked with the remote comm functionality.